# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ModelA]' to type 'ModelA'

Tags: c#, json, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

This error is driving me crazy. It used to work. Now it doesn't. Not sure what change caused it and I can't roll back without losing a lot of stuff.

```
 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Literrater.Models.ranges]' 
 to type 'Literrater.Models.ranges'.
```

Here's the model.

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectDocID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string quote { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CommentVote> CommentVote { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReply> CommentReply { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReport> CommentReport { get; set; }
    public ProjectDoc ProjectDoc { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ranges> ranges { get; set; }
}
public class ranges
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string startOffset { get; set; }
    public string endOffset { get; set; }


}
```

Action that throws an error

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create(Comment comment)
    {
        comment.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        comment.UserID = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        db.Comments.Add(comment); //Error here
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(comment);
```

Json being posted.

```
 {"text":"",
  "ranges":
       [{
            "start":"/p[1]",
            "startOffset":160,
            "end":"/p[1]",
            "endOffset":234
       }],
   "quote":"es. Hadn't they ever heard of potpourri? Each incessant beep, made by the",
   "UserID":"6",
   "ProjectDocID":"1"
 }
```

Update: Screenshots from old working database
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the error is in `db.Comments.Add(comment)` we really need to know what the database is... it sounds like you've got a model mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @Jon I'm using Entity Framework with code-first migrations (this is all just offline local development right now) if that's what you mean?

Comment: Right - we didn't know it was EF before. How does your `List<ranges>` appear in the database? Why isn't it a virtual `ICollection<ranges>` property, like the others?

Comment: I don't have a reason? It just worked before. Just learning all of this. I changed it to an ICollection deleted/seeded the database (no effect).

Comment: So what does the column look like in the database? Do your other multi-element properties work? You really need to separate out the JSON side from the EF side: get each to work separately, *then* put them together.

Comment: Add screen of the database in the older working version. This code used to work. If I copy and past the action and model from the old code it still doesn't work. Debugging shows the same data, in the same for, as the same type being read into the action. I did recently update to VS 2012 ultimate if that helps. I'm not sure what else I could have done to cause this.

Comment: If you have the old model, presumably that wouldn't even *have* a `List<ranges>`, so do you get a different error? I'm afraid at this point we're out of my particular comfort zone, which makes it harder to guess at possible causes.

Comment: The old model (the one that works) is identical to the one above. Thanks for taking the time to try and help Jon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of hours of replacing one file at a time it appear that my DAL Context file had this fluent API statement.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ranges>().HasRequired(p => p.Comment);
```

I don't know why I added it, but commenting it out made the error go away. If someone could explain it that would be sweet.

Turns out I did it so I could delete the comment, which doesn't work now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out that I had a one-to-many relationship in my xml source:

```
  <one-to-many name="physicalLocations"
           propertyDefinintion="Defines the physical location of the department"
           typeName="POCO.BO.Location"
           nullable="false"
           dbColumn="DepartmentId" />
```

But still had a foreign key relation value in the generated C# file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the physical location of the department
    /// </summary>
    public const string F_PHYSICALLOCATIONS = "PhysicalLocations";
    [ForeignKey("PhysicalLocations")]
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    private Location _physicalLocations;
    public virtual Location PhysicalLocations { get { return _physicalLocations; } set { _physicalLocations = value; } }
```

So it was actually one-to-one rather than one-to-many.  I fixed it like this:

```
  <one-to-one name="physicalLocations"
           propertyDefinintion="Defines the physical location of the department"
           typeName="POCO.BO.Location"
           nullable="false"
           dbColumn="DepartmentId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error, and ultimately the same cause - EF had been given an inconsistent understanding of the nature of the relationship.

In my case we're using annotation-based models, with the DB structure managed independently. I'd inadvertantly set the model up wrong...

## DB Structure:

- I had a Parent table, and a Child Table. One Parent to many Children.
- Child table has ParentId column FKing to Parent.
- Child table has no Artificial PK.
- Child table has a Natural PK of ParentId + Col1 + Col2.

## Bad EF Setup:

In Parent

```
    public ICollection<TriangleCell> Cells { get; set; }
```

In Child

```
    [Key]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentId ))]
    public ParentTable Parent{ get; set; }

    public int Col1 { get; set; }
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
    public int ValueCol { get; set; }
```

I believe that because only ParentId was marked as `Key`, therefore EF inferred the relations must be one-to-one and everything went wrong.

Marking the rest of the Natural Key in the model class fixed the error.

## Good EF Setup:

In Parent

```
    public ICollection<TriangleCell> Cells { get; set; }
```

In Child

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentId ))]
    public ParentTable Parent{ get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Col1 { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Col2 { get; set; }

    public int ValueCol { get; set; }
```